# Can you recommend a full-text search engine?

Tags: c++, indexing, full-text-search, search-engine, autosuggest

Can you recommend a full-text search engine? (Preferably open source)

I have a database of many (though relatively short) HTML documents.  I want users to be able to search this database by entering one or more search words in my C++ desktop application.  Hence, I’m looking for a fast full-text search solution to integrate with my app.  Ideally, it should:

- Skip common words, such as `the`, `of`, `and`, etc.
- Support stemming, i.e. search for `run` also finds documents containing `runner`, `running` and `ran`.
- Be able to update its index in the background as new documents are added to the database.
- Be able to provide search word suggestions (like Google Suggest)
- Have a well-documented API

To illustrate, assume the database has just two documents:

> *Document 1*:  `This is a test of text search.`
>
> *Document 2*:  `Testing is fun.`

The following words should be in the index:  `fun`, `search`, `test`, `testing`, `text`.  If the user types `t` in the search box, I want the application to be able to suggest `test`, `testing` and `text` (Ideally, the application should be able to query the search engine for the 10 most common search words starting with `t`).  A search for `testing` should return both documents.

Other points:

- I don't need multi-user support
- I don't need support for complex queries
- The database resides on the user's computer, so the indexing should be performed locally.

Can you suggest a C or C++ based solution?  (I’ve briefly reviewed [CLucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) and [Xapian](http://xapian.org), but I’m not sure if either will address my needs, especially querying the search word indexes for the suggest feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have use with very success the [dtSearch](http://www.dtsearch.com) module.

They have a dll, that you can use with your application to index just anything and do more than the one you ask.

**Note:** Is not free.

I do not see in question that you ask for free one, so I write my favor one.
The dtSearch have inspire me and I create an indexer for my language Ellinika for my sites, because did not found what I was looking for my language.

There are some modules just for steeming if you just need to find suggestions for your words, I have get reference from here http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/

For example if you have a database like ms sql that all ready do some basic indexing, and some one search for a word, and you do not find nothing, you can do by your self steeming on this word, and search again...

Answer (score 4):

Also check out [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: Not really open-source anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Clucene for c/c++ and sphider for php. both are free but take time to setup and use, but not difficult to understand.